# Averaging an indefinite signal

Tags: matlab, filter, simulink

I am trying to average a signal which is coming to my simulink model (unknown initial condition). I can pass on the first value as it is, But the 2nd value must be averaged with the first before passing it on and the must be averaged with the average of first two and so on. Can I just give initial condition as 0 for the first case?

But the problem is the length of the signal is unknown, I can keep getting signal until I run my program. I thought of moving average filter, but not sure how to proceed with this.

If anyone can point me in right direction.

Comment: I'd try a [one-pole recursive filter](http://www.earlevel.com/main/2012/12/15/a-one-pole-filter/): `y[n] = a*x[n] + (1-a)*y[n-1]`. That automatically gives less weight (exponentially so) to input samples more distant in the past. The parameter `a` controls the amount of averaging, or the inertia of the filter

Comment: Theres a [moving average](https://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/movingaverage.html) block. Setting window length off gives the cummulative moving average.

Comment: @jodag consider answering the question ;)

Comment: @LuisMendo I was just interested in your formula. Is it (1-a) or (a-1). and what exactly do u mean a controls the amount of averaging?

Comment: It is `1-a`. The parameter `a` controls the cutoff frequency of the lowpas filter, that is, the approximate time-width on which the average is applied. See for example [here](https://tomroelandts.com/articles/low-pass-single-pole-iir-filter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the DSP System Toolbox then can use the [Moving Average](https://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/movingaverage.html) block. Turn off "Specify window length" to get the cumulative moving average.

Comment: unfortunately I do not have DSP tool box, I am trying to implement it by hand using a delay block. But the problem is with the initial condition. I wrote it wrong, it cannot be 0. It has to be the same as the first value.

Answer (score 0):

You want a **Cumulative moving average**.

Its equation is quite simple

```
average=(newpoint+average*npoints)/(npoints+1);
npoits++
```